# Export excel file from frontend using Angularjs getting an unusual content error when write the excel file through plugin js-xlsx

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, npm, js-xlsx

**On opening the excel file whcih is export in .xlsm format file getting the above below error[image]**

**Please look at the below code in controller on write the excel file**

Angular Controller Function using js-xls plugin.
Used two plugin named js-xls and filesaver.js for saveAs blob function

```
      $scope.exportData = function(){
          function Workbook() {
            if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
            this.SheetNames = [];
            this.Sheets = {};
          }

          function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data, opts) {
            var ws = {};
            var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
            for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
              for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
                if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
                var cell = {v: data[R][C] };
                if(cell.v == null) continue;
                var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

                /* TEST: proper cell types and value handling */
                if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                  cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                  cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                }
                else cell.t = 's';

                //ws['!cols'][C].wch = cell.v.length;
                ws[cell_ref] = cell;
              }
            }

            /* TEST: proper range */
            if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
            return ws;
          }
          var newArr = [[1,2],[3,4]];
          var ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(newArr);

            var  wb = new Workbook();
            wb.SheetNames.push('DemoSheet');
            wb.Sheets['DemoSheet'] = ws;
            console.log('Object of workbook');
            console.log(ws);
            //var stereotypes = Object.keys($scope.childrenAttrsMap);
            //console.log(stereotypes);

            var wopts = { bookType:'xlsm', bookSST:false, type:'binary' };
            var wbout = XLSX.write(wb,wopts);
            console.log(wbout);

            function s2ab(s) {
              var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
              var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
              for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
              return buf;
            }
            /* the saveAs call downloads a file on the local machine */
            saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}),  "Gen_Safe1_data.xlsm");
  }
```

Comment: How many rows are you trying to write in the sheet? Do you need xlsm output instead of xlsx?

Comment: Right now i am inserting only two rows in a sheet. xlsm output is not necessary but i tried with xlsx format but then it will give me corrupt file error

Comment: Can you try modifying c:10000000, r:10000000 to c:100, r:100 everywhere in your code (also range.s.c < 10000000 to range.s.c < 100) and see if the error persists?

Comment: yes i tried using this still i am getting this error

Comment: Above error is solved if i load template.xlsm file consisting of dummy macros data and then write the file consisting of tabular data then it will be able to successfully export the excel file with .xlsm format without above warnings